# How to do an HTTP request from Parse (Parse Cloud Code)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, heroku, parse-platform, httprequest

I am trying to do an HTTP request from Parse to a Heroku Server. I am currently getting this error from the XCode console when calling the function "saveToDatabase":

> myApp[1400:88895]
>   [Error]: Uncaught init failed:not supported argument (Code: 141,
>   Version: 1.7.5) Parse Cloud function failed to be called to generate
>   token with error: Optional(Error Domain=Parse Code=141 "Uncaught init
>   failed:not supported argument" UserInfo=0x7fd2a2d5abf0 {code=141,
>   originalError=Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1011 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1011.)", temporary=0,
>   error=Uncaught init failed:not supported argument,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Uncaught init failed:not supported argument})

```
 Parse.Cloud.define("saveToDatabase", function(request, response)  {
  var userInformation = { id: 1003 };
  var userJSON = JSON.stringify(userInformation);
  var plz = "success";

  return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    url: 'https://myApp.herokuapp.com/saveUserToDatabase',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: userJSON
  }).then(function(httpResponse) {
    response.success(httpResponse.text);
  },
  function (error) {
    console.error('Log response: ' + error.text);
  });
});
```

Below is the Heroku Code:

```
app.post('/saveUserToDatabase', function(request, response) {
  response.status(200).end();
});
```

This is the function I am using to invoke the Parse Cloud code:

```
func saveData)  {
        println("Calling saveToDatabase...")
        PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("saveToDatabase", withParameters: ["userID": 1007]) { (object:AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                println("NO error...")
            }
            else {
                println("This is the error: \(error)")
            }
        }

    }
```

I have tried everything I could think of. What am I misunderstanding in this code?

Comment: Could we see the call to the cloud function?  Maybe the problem is invoking the cloud function, not the httpRequest within it.  Another way to rule that out is to test a version of this that will just echo the parameters: instead of calling httpRequest, just call `response.success(request);`